# Подсчет количества торговых дней в году на питоне

Tags: python

**Помогите, пожалуйста, с подсчетом количества торговых дней в каждом году.**
**Здесь я загружаю биржевые данные с помощью пакета yahoo finance.**

```
pip install yfinance

import yfinance as yf

import pandas as pd

tickers_list = ['AAPL', 'EA']

data = pd.DataFrame(columns=tickers_list)

for ticker in tickers_list:
   data = yf.download(ticker,'2015-01-01','2021-01-01')
```

**Так как акции 2, надо как-то подсчитать отдельно количество торговых дней у каждой ежегодно в период с 2015.01.01 - 2021.01.01**
[image: Здесь я загружаю биржевые данные с помощью пакета yahoo finance.]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Здесь я рассматриваю только данные по открытию торгового дня, поправив немного код**

```
for ticker in tickers_list:
    data[ticker] = yf.download(ticker,'2015-01-01','2021-01-01')['Open']
```

Comment: вопрос для уточнения: а как вы понимаете, что акций 2?

Comment: Да, все таки из выходного датафрейма не очевидно, что вы работаете с 2 акциями, поэтому постобработка сложна. Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63107801/10562663) есть решение для добавления указания tickera. У вас условие что вы можете загружать только так? Можно ли рассмотреть вариант с раздельными загрузками по отдельным акциям и отдельным годам, чтобы вследствии считать количество строк, что будет равно количеству рабочих дней. Судя по [документации](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance) функция загрузки очень гибкая

Comment: Вы в цикле перезаписываете переменную “data” поэтому у вас в “data” всегда будет только одна акция (последняя из списка “ tickers_list”)

Comment: @Елена совершенно верно, но dataframe, который вы получаете на выходе не содержит данной информации. Как вы будете понимать какие данные относятся к каким акциям? [Решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63107801/10562663) от Trenton McKinney в моем предыущем комментраии содержит информацию как это добавить.

Comment: @Дмитрий, в tickers_list я добавила только тикеры акций Apple и Electronic Arts. В самом вопросе отобразила как это можно увидеть. Честно говоря, не знаю как можно раздельно по годам и акциям, если только разбить весь этот код, прописывая отдельно каждую акцию и год. Спасибо за ссылку гитхаб! Сейчас посмотрю что оттуда можно узнать)

Comment: Вот последний `for` уже содержит 2 дополнительные колонки с `AAPL` и `EA`. Только остальная информация по колонкам содержит не релевантные данные к ним обоим, а только к `EA`-акции. Мой вопрос был таков: можете ли вы использовать несколько раз скачивание файлов и указывать период в один год? Если да, тогда вы просто можете посчитать количество строк для одного года и так для каждой акции, что и будет той информацией которую вы ищете. Все точно также укладывается в for

Comment: @Дмитрий, да, так можно сделать, но необходимо как-то сделать таблицу со значениями для большего количества акций. Мне надо не просто узнать эти значения, а как-то показать. Извините, что так поздно отвечаю

Comment: @Елена вообще не проблема=). Один совет и можете ему не следовать, но чтобы понять и конкретезировать задачу, напишите на листочке все столбцы, которые вы хотите получить, для начала. Т. е. добавление столбцов, которые не имеют ничего общего со строками - это не корректно. Далее поймите как будете работать с данными дат. Может `pandas` уже содержит инструменты (я этого не знаю, но почему то уверен, что содержит) и все что вам надо это найти в документации данный раздел.